# Deadlock and Resource ordering

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having trouble debugging the grid lock in the code below (meant to compute the Spanning Forest of a graph, not necessarily the minimum spanning forest). I was careful in the code to always acquire the lock of the node with a higher index first, but I am still getting deadlock when I run it. I was wondering if I had any idea where my locking strategy is going wrong? I attempt to debug with with the Eclipse debugger, but nothing really appeared to stand out as to what could be causing it.

Link to full code: https://github.com/lstrait2/parallel_SF?files=1

```
public class SFRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        private int start_idx;
        private int end_idx;
        private Graph.Node[] u_ancestors;
        private Graph.Node[] v_ancestors;
            private ArrayList<Graph.Edge> edges;
        private ConcurrentHashMap<Graph.Node,Graph.Node> newAncestors;


        public SFRunnable(
            int start, 
            int end, 
            ArrayList<Graph.Edge> edges, 
            Graph.Node[] u_ancestors, 
            Graph.Node[] v_ancestors, 
            ConcurrentHashMap<Graph.Node,Graph.Node> newAncestors
        ) {
            this.start_idx = start;
            this.end_idx = end;
            this.edges = edges;
            this.u_ancestors = u_ancestors;
            this.v_ancestors = v_ancestors;
            this.newAncestors = newAncestors;
        }
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i = this.start_idx; i < this.end_idx; i++)
            {
                Graph.Edge e = this.edges.get(i);
                buildSF(i,this.u_ancestors,this.v_ancestors,this.newAncestors);
            }
        }

        private Graph.Node ancestorOf(
            final Graph.Node u, 
            ConcurrentHashMap<Graph.Node, Graph.Node> newAncestors
        ) {
            Graph.Node newAncestor;
            if(u.ancestor != u)
            {
                return u.ancestor;
            }
            else if( (newAncestor = newAncestors.get(u)) != null)
            {
                return newAncestor;
            }
            return u;
        }

        private void buildSF(
            int i, 
            Graph.Node[] u_ancestors, 
            Graph.Node[] v_ancestors, 
            ConcurrentHashMap<Graph.Node, Graph.Node> newAncestors
        ) {

            Graph.Edge e = this.edges.get(i);

            if(e.u.index < e.v.index)
            {
                synchronized(e.v)
                {
                    Graph.Node v_ancestor = e.v;
                    synchronized(e.u)
                    {
                        Graph.Node u_ancestor = e.u;
                        buildSF(e,i,u_ancestors,v_ancestors,newAncestors,u_ancestor,v_ancestor);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(e.u)
                {
                    Graph.Node u_ancestor = e.u;
                    synchronized(e.v)
                    {
                        Graph.Node v_ancestor = e.v;
                        buildSF(e,i,u_ancestors,v_ancestors,newAncestors,u_ancestor,v_ancestor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private void buildSF(
            Graph.Edge e, 
            int i, 
            Graph.Node[] u_ancestors, 
            Graph.Node[] v_ancestors, 
            ConcurrentHashMap<Graph.Node,Graph.Node> newAncestors, 
            Graph.Node u_ancestor, 
            Graph.Node v_ancestor
        ) {
            // locks acquired for u_ancestor and v_ancestor in previous call
            Graph.Node nextAncestor_u = ancestorOf(u_ancestor,newAncestors);
            Graph.Node nextAncestor_v = ancestorOf(v_ancestor,newAncestors);

            if(nextAncestor_u == u_ancestor && nextAncestor_v == v_ancestor)
            {
                if(u_ancestor == v_ancestor)
                    return;

                if(u_ancestor.index < v_ancestor.index)
                {
                    // swap nodes
                    Graph.Node temp = u_ancestor;
                    u_ancestor = v_ancestor;
                    v_ancestor = temp;
                }

                u_ancestors[i] = u_ancestor;
                v_ancestors[i] = v_ancestor;
                newAncestors.put(u_ancestor,v_ancestor);
            }
            else
            {

                if(nextAncestor_u == u_ancestor)
                {
                    synchronized(nextAncestor_v)
                    {
                        buildSF(e,i,u_ancestors,v_ancestors,newAncestors,u_ancestor,nextAncestor_v);
                    }
                }

                else if(nextAncestor_v == v_ancestor)
                {
                    synchronized(nextAncestor_u)
                    {
                        buildSF(e,i,u_ancestors,v_ancestors,newAncestors,nextAncestor_u,v_ancestor);
                    }
                }
                else if(nextAncestor_u.index < nextAncestor_v.index)
                {
                    synchronized(nextAncestor_v)
                    {
                        buildSF(e,i,u_ancestors,v_ancestors,newAncestors,u_ancestor,nextAncestor_v);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(nextAncestor_u)
                    {
                        buildSF(e,i,u_ancestors,v_ancestors,newAncestors,nextAncestor_u,v_ancestor);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Here is the graph code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Graph
{
    static class Node
    {
        final int index;
        Node ancestor;

        Node(int index)
        {
            this.index = index;
            ancestor = this;
        }


    }


    static class Edge
    {
        final Node u, v;
        boolean inSF = false;

        Edge(Node u, Node v)
        {
            this.u = u;
            this.v = v;
        }

    }



    ArrayList<Edge> edges;
    Node[] nodes;

    public Graph()
    {
        edges = new ArrayList<>();
        nodes = new Node[0];
    }

    static Graph readEdgeGraph(String file) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        Graph g = new Graph();

        if(!"EdgeArray".equals(reader.readLine()))
            throw new IOException("invalid edge graph format");

        while(true)
        {
            String line;

            try
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
            }catch(EOFException e){ break;}


            if(line == null)
                break;

            String[] words = line.split("[ \t]+");
            if(words.length != 2)
                throw new IOException("invalid edge graph format");

            int u = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
            int v = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);

            Node U = g.getVertex(u);
            Node V = g.getVertex(v);

            g.addEdge(U,V);
        }
        return g;
    }

    public Node getVertex(int n)
    {
        if(nodes.length < n)
            nodes = Arrays.copyOf(nodes, n+1+ n/2);

        if(nodes[n] == null)
            nodes[n] = new Node(n);

        return nodes[n];
    }

    public void addEdge(Node u, Node v)
    {
        Edge edge = new Edge(u,v);
        edges.add(edge);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add a `main` method to make your code a *complete* program? That way we can run it as well, and reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I added a link to the full code

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that in the first buildSF method, e.u.index can be equal to e.v.index.  In this case, two threads could try to lock the two Graph.Node objects with equal indices in opposite orders, which could cause a deadlock.

Also, within the synchronized block, you call the other buildSF method, which synchronizes on a third Graph.Node; the third Graph.Node may not have a lower index than both of the Graph.Node objects that the thread has already locked, so that could also cause a deadlock.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I added in the graph code if that helps.

Comment: Aren't the locks all acquired in index order though? I tried to be careful about that

Comment: I confirmed that the second call to the buildSF method was the problem (the ancestor  doesn't always have a smaller index than the two nodes locked in the first call). Is there an easy way to get around this?